# Compile only Intel Fortran Project

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, intel-fortran

This is what I want to achieve, if it's possible. My hopes are not high.

Have a Fortran project in Visual Studio with several .FOR files that are dependent on other files. I want to only compile these files, without linking, equivalent to Command Prompt

```
ifort /c
```

Then, I would add the resulting .OBJ files as dependencies in other projects that need them, and there the linking would happen.

Comment: Say I have a single .FOR file which has a bunch of functions defined in it that I want to use in several other projects. If I add that file to every project, every project would have to compile that file for itself, and that would make compile time very long.
This way, I compile it only once, and use that .OBJ file in all other projects.

Comment: Use a static library fortran project.  Put the FOR file in that.  Build it.  Then all your other projects can reference that one static library.  That is what static library projects are for!!!

Comment: Do what @IanH suggests.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll try that. For now, I have put /FORCE as the additional linker option, so it reports a successful build (disregards missing externals) and I have my .OBJ file. Your suggestions sounds less messy, though.

Comment: Don't do that.  You are best off asking questions like this on the Intel forum at https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/

Comment: @IanH I ended up doing what you suggested with static libraries and it worked like a charm. If you post it  as an answer I would flag it as solution.